# Macros for creating named constructors

Tags: c++

I am trying to play with c++ and macros for the first time. SO basically in a lecture I know where a coded value is used to distinguish different modes of an object (game_type in this case), then these objects must be created via constructors with meaningful named constructors. SO  I created  createSinglePlayerGame() and named constructors. Then I tried to optimize this code using macros. SO In the Game class I define the function- like macro consructor A ## operator which runs parameter replacement on the two identifiers  and then concatenates the result  ("token pasting).

Can you look at  my code and suggest a better way of doing this, also do you see any hygiene problem that my macros may be used incorrectly,

```
 class Game
    {
    public:
    #define CONSTRUCTOR(name, a) static Game create_##name() { return Game(a);}

            CONSTRUCTOR(Single, 0)
            CONSTRUCTOR(Multiple, 2)


        // named constructors
        static Game createSinglePlayerGame() { return Game(0); }
        static Game createMultiPlayerGame() { return Game(1); }

    protected:
        Game(int game_type);
    };
    int main()
    {
        Game myGame = Game::createSinglePlayerGame();
        Game second = Game::create_Single();

    }
```

Comment: Always avoid macros whenever you can. Only use macros when there is no other way to do what you want (which is almost never).

Comment: There is nothing "formally" wrong with macros but IMO I try to avoid using them because compiler does not "understand" them. Did you consider using templates instead?

Comment: Thank you very much Just - I was excercising and  actually my final was  to write a C++ macro that can used to declare named constructors with a variable number of arguments.But actually I don't think it would be possible with macros or maybe I just understand so good yet the macros

Answer (score 5):

A more conventional way would be:

```
enum class GameType {
    SinglePlayer,
    MultiPlayer,
};

class Game
{
public:
    explicit Game(GameType type);
};

int main()
{
    Game myGame(GameType::SinglePlayer);
}
```

This is simpler and will be less surprising for other C++ developers to read.  It's also less error-prone: even your example code confuses `1` and `2` for multiplayer mode, and since you use raw integers to store it, there's no complaint from the compiler.  Using `enum class` it will be much harder to make such mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much Just - I was just excercising and  actually my final  aim was  to write a C++ macro that can used to declare named constructors with a variable number of arguments.But actually I don't think it would be possible with macros or maybe I just understand so good yet the macros

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to John Zwincks solution, you can also use inheritance:

```
class Game {
protected:
    Game(int game_type);
};

class SinglePlayerGame: public Game {
public:
    SinglePlayerGame(): Game(0) {}
};

class MultiPlayerGame: public Game {
public:
    MultiPlayerGame(): Game(1) {}
};

int main() {
    SinglePlayerGame myGame;
    ...
}
```

Although I would only use this method if there were more differences in the interface between single- and multiplayer games than just the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative to macros you can also use templates. Templates is something that compiler "understand" and optimize.

Their syntax may be confusing at start but if you play with them you can get used to it...

```
// Tag types for template dispatching
struct SinglePlayer {};
struct MultiPlayer {};

// Default single player
template <typename G>
class Game {
    public:
        Game () { /* create default single player game */ }
};

// Specialization for multi player
template <>
class Game <MultiPlayer> {
    public:
        Game () { /* create multiplayer player game */}
};

int main (void) {
    Game g1 = Game<SinglePlayer>();
    Game g2 = Game<MultiPlayer>();
}
```

This approach split the class definition into 2. One for single player and one for multi player. If they share a lot of common staff and you believe that this should not be the case, you may consider to avoid the class template and use `std::enable_if<>` in the constructor's level.

For example:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Tag types for template dispatching
struct SinglePlayer{};
struct MultiPlayer{};

struct Game {
    public:
    template <
        typename G,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<G, SinglePlayer>::value, int> = 0
    >
    Game(G) { /* create a single player game */ }
    template <
        typename G,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<G, MultiPlayer>::value, int> = 0
    >
    Game(G) { /* create a multi player game */ }
};

int main (void) {
    Game g1 = Game(SinglePlayer{});
    Game g2 = Game(MultiPlayer{});
}
```

Notice that there is no class template any more, only a [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) dispatch for the constructors. The disadvantage is the dummy pass of a `SinglePlayer{}` or `MultiPlayer{}` object to the constructor.